# Quickest way to setup a local Oracle Database in local development

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am currently involved in the setup of a local Windows development environment consisting in the classic Angularjs -> Nodejs -> JEE -> Oracle 11g

I cannot have immediate help from the infrastructure team, so the only available option is to manually install and setup the whole dev environment on my local dev and provide software and instructions to other junior developers.

The time consuming part is the Oracle setup that also involve several time consuming scripts (schema creation, table setup ecc...) to be run, that also need SQLDeveloper.

I have currently prepared the full environment, and I was wondering what option I have in this case.

1. Can I just zip the Oracle folder and pass to other developers that may change/create their path or environment variables ? It is a default installation and I can see that two folders are created: one in `c:\app\<username>` and the other in `c:\Program Files\Oracle`
2. If option one is not feasible, at least I wanted to provide a quick backup to be easily restored possibly without SQLDeveloper. What option do I have in this case, a dump or a script with create, insert, alter ?

I also have another problem not strictly related to the question. For company policy some of the developers doesn't have administrator privileges on local machine required by Oracle setup. They can have temporarily admin users in order to complete setup, but the results is that all the Windows services will be installed under admin, and they cannot be stopped or started manually.

Comment: "*Can I just zip the Oracle folder and pass to other developers*" - no, that's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way out - from my point of view - would be to install Virtual Box to all those computers, download one of [pre-built developer virtual machines](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html), copy them to those computers and that's it ... you have everything you wanted.

As there are "several time consuming scripts", I guess that you'd want to run them first on one VM copy; create everything you need (users, tables, load data, whatever) and THEN let other developers use it.

Benefit? Keep one copy for you (the one where everything is set up as you wanted); when someone needs a fresh start, replace their VM with the "original" one.

Such an approach (virtual machine) solves your 2nd question; everyone's their own *administrator* there, and it won't affect the host computer (no need for them to be administrators on the host).

By the way, answer to your 1st question is "No", that won't work.

P.S. Ah, yes - you tagged the question with "11g". I don't think that it is available on pre-built VMs. If it has to be that version, no problem - approach is the same: create your own virtual machine (for example, I use one under MS Windows XP, with Developer suite 10g on it), install anything you need (database 11g (perhaps XE version?), SQL Developer, any other tool ... ) and call it *your own pre-built VM*.

Comment: Yes exactly like that, version is 11g. The scripts already exist so I am planning to provide a full prepared DB and then pass to others. The virtual box solution is nice, but I am not a system administrator, and I am worried about incurring in network problems, I would need to setup a VPN on it as well as the code repository and some other things are on client network. But...are you talking about having a DB on a virtual machine, or the whole env  ?

Comment: Exactly; everything on the virtual machine (database + SQL Developer + ...). Think of it as if you were a teacher who wants to prepare environment for his students. Class takes two weeks to finish, and then you'll get new students. Just give them prepared VMs and they are ready to go. At least, that's how I understood the problem. It wouldn't make sense, otherwise - you'd set up **one** database and let anyone connect to it, but you wouldn't need anything "special" in that case, just install SQL Developer for everyone.

Comment: You could also consider using a container from Oracle container registry: https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:14536083385734:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:803,803,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,1,0&cs=3CGuyAjF4lZUfVCIO_RiEhlz6mPk1TYKqBsd8258GcUZyyl8QjcOR1uxDNFMMtyzc1wh4lRww7xjgKWpmQ62rMA